# problem with \raggedcolumns

Tags: multicol

I want to have two columns but the first column should go until the end of the page and then the second column should start. As in other posts suggested I tried \raggedcolumns, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, text={16.5cm, 25.2cm}, centering]{geometry}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}


\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}

\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\textbf{des verbes iregulliers}

\vspace{16pt}


\begin{multicols}{2}
\raggedcolumns

\begin{easylist}[itemize]

& venir $\to$ venu(e)
& sortir $\to$ sorti(e)
& partir $\to$ parti(e)
& descendre $\to$descendu(e)
& faire $\to$ fait 
& entendre $\to$ entendu
& oublier $\to$ oubli
& lire $\to$ lu
& naitre $\to$ né(e)
& avoir $\to$ eu
& être $\to$ été
& pouvoir $\to$ pu
& vouloir $\to$ voulu
& voir $\to$ vu
& devoir $\to$ dû
& savoir $\to$ su 
& croire $\to$ cru
& perdre $\to$ perdu
& boire $\to$ bu
& connaître $\to$ connu
& mettre $\to$ mis
& prendre $\to$ pris
& comprendre $\to$ compris
& apprendre $\to$ appris
& ouvrir $\to$ ouvert
& offrir $\to$ offert
& découvrir $\to$ découvert
& dire $\to$ dit
& écrire $\to$ écrit
& mourir $\to$ mort(e)

\end{easylist}

\end{multicols}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `\begin{multicols*}{2}` and `\end{multicols*}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`multicols` environment always balances the columns of the last page. The example has only one page, so this is also the last page and the columns are balanced. A very simple solution could be to use the kernel `\twocolumn` instead of `multicols`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, text={16.5cm, 25.2cm}, centering]{geometry}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}


\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn[\textbf{des verbes iregulliers}\par
\vspace{16pt}]


\begin{easylist}[itemize]

& venir $\to$ venu(e)
& sortir $\to$ sorti(e)
& partir $\to$ parti(e)
& descendre $\to$descendu(e)
& faire $\to$ fait 
& entendre $\to$ entendu
& oublier $\to$ oubli
& lire $\to$ lu
& naitre $\to$ né(e)
& avoir $\to$ eu
& être $\to$ été
& pouvoir $\to$ pu
& vouloir $\to$ voulu
& voir $\to$ vu
& devoir $\to$ dû
& savoir $\to$ su 
& croire $\to$ cru
& perdre $\to$ perdu
& boire $\to$ bu
& connaître $\to$ connu
& mettre $\to$ mis
& prendre $\to$ pris
& comprendre $\to$ compris
& apprendre $\to$ appris
& ouvrir $\to$ ouvert
& offrir $\to$ offert
& découvrir $\to$ découvert
& dire $\to$ dit
& écrire $\to$ écrit
& mourir $\to$ mort(e)
\end{easylist}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But if you like to use package `multicol`, since version 1.5q the package has also an environment `multicols*` that does not balance the last page:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, text={16.5cm, 25.2cm}, centering]{geometry}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}


\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}

\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\textbf{des verbes iregulliers}

\vspace{16pt}


\begin{multicols*}{2}

\begin{easylist}[itemize]

& venir $\to$ venu(e)
& sortir $\to$ sorti(e)
& partir $\to$ parti(e)
& descendre $\to$descendu(e)
& faire $\to$ fait 
& entendre $\to$ entendu
& oublier $\to$ oubli
& lire $\to$ lu
& naitre $\to$ né(e)
& avoir $\to$ eu
& être $\to$ été
& pouvoir $\to$ pu
& vouloir $\to$ voulu
& voir $\to$ vu
& devoir $\to$ dû
& savoir $\to$ su 
& croire $\to$ cru
& perdre $\to$ perdu
& boire $\to$ bu
& connaître $\to$ connu
& mettre $\to$ mis
& prendre $\to$ pris
& comprendre $\to$ compris
& apprendre $\to$ appris
& ouvrir $\to$ ouvert
& offrir $\to$ offert
& découvrir $\to$ découvert
& dire $\to$ dit
& écrire $\to$ écrit
& mourir $\to$ mort(e)

\end{easylist}

\end{multicols*}



\end{document}
```

[image: multicols*]